# What to return when Nothing in a function of type Maybe a -> Svg Msg in Elm

Tags: elm

I have a function to render a Maybe Block as a Svg rect

```
type alias Block = {x:Int, y:Int}
type alias Prey = Maybe Block
renderPrey : Prey -> Svg Msg
renderPrey prey =
    case prey of
         Maybe.Just block -> --Svg rect  returns Svg msg
         Nothing -> -- how do I return something like Svg.none?
```

I see there is no Svg.none http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/svg/2.0.0/Svg

The workaround solution I have is by changing signature

```
renderPrey : Prey -> List(Svg Msg)
renderPrey prey =
    case prey of
         Maybe.Just block -> [--Svg rect  returns Svg msg]
         Nothing -> []
```

Comment: Your workaround seems fine. You could also propagate the `Maybe` by returning `Maybe (Svg Msg)` and dealing with it in the calling function.

Comment: Hooray : you have discovered `fold` in the Haskell sense

Answer (score 3):

I use `Svg.text ""`. So far I haven't had any issues with it, but I haven't written a lot of SVG.

Comment: You can also return an empty svg element, like `g [] []`.